# How to install an External Global tool with Nuke

Tags: dotnetnuke, nuke-build

I am using Nuke for my running CI steps for my .NET Core Apps. I am useing coverlet and reportgenerator for coverage analysis and report generation.
I know that there are global tools for coverlet and reportgenerator, but I  do not know a way I can be sure that the CI agents have Reportgenerator or even nuke global tool installed.

Is there a way I can install dotnet tools like reportgenerator on the go if it does not already exist in the CI agent?

Comment: did you read the documentation?

Comment: I could not find a helpful part of documentation regarding this. But I was able to use dotnet tools manifest and restore to achieve this anyway.. I also used PackageDownload in nuke build project csproj as nuke recommended.

Comment: @Matthias I couldnt find a documentation page that lists the available nuke options like nuke :setup, :addpackage etc. Is there one?

Comment: `PackageDownload` is exactly what you need, it's all documented here: http://www.nuke.build/docs/authoring-builds/cli-tools.html